# redirects to .aspx page on click of submit button

Tags: redirect

I hAve created a oob feedback form that displays as a modal popup. I have hidden the cancel button and changed the name of save as submit. Now when i submit the feedback the modal popup gets closed and the feedback gets saved.

I want that on click of submit button the feedback Should get saved which is already happening but once user clicks on submit the popup should close and it should redirect me to another page. I have already created that page as thankyou.aspx

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `Source` query string parameter in your model pop up window.

`ModalDialog.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fservername%2Fsitename%2Fthankyou.aspx`

For more details check this [link.](http://sympmarc.com/2009/10/20/passing-a-source-parameter-on-the-query-string-with-multiple-other-parameters/)

Comment: Garima this is the path of my page http//arospdev01/functions/isandit/tsg/hr/sitepages/thankyou.aspx

Comment: check the link. You can add relative path too in Source attribute.

Comment: Can u explain the complete steps.I am not able to understand where i have to change the source parameter.

Comment: Suppose your feedback form is feesback.aspx. you must be specifying the url of this form somewhere. Just add the Source query string param at the end. Ex feedback.aspx?Source={relative url of thankyou.aspx page}